# How do I make my intous 4 wacom affect only one Monitor?

Tags: xorg, input-devices, wacom, graphics-tablet

I have two monitors and I want my wacom to only work on one monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not currently possible with Ubuntu. You'd need to program xorg to focus one core pointer towards one specific screen and I don't know of any way that's possible.

You could however suggest it as a feature for xorg by reporting a bug:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

I suspect that you may be using an nvidia card, if this is the case then you are using twinview which distorts the dimensions of the desktop (because it's fake, it's one desktop over two displays, instead of two desktops like ATI and Intel), to set this up just use xsetwacom:

```
xsetwacom --list
```

This will tell you the names of your pen device, then use that in the next command:

```
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos3 4x6 stylus" TwinView horizontal
```

To put it back to normal, use:

```
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos3 4x6 stylus" TwinView none
```

You should need to set stylus, eraser and pointer to get all your devices set right. Once you can see how it works, copy and paste the commands into a new hidden file called `.xinitrc` in your home folder, you can use a normal text editor to make the file.

Now you should have good wacom settings when you reboot. (side note: you can use `xsetwacom --list param` to get a list of all the options you can set.)